# Google Chart : How do I add select event handler to the pie chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I was able to generate pie chart successfully. However, when I was trying to add a select event listener to the pie chart, it is not triggering the function at all.

```
function handlePieChartResponse(response)
    {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }
        var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
        if (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() <= 0) {
            document.getElementById('dummyTableRow').innerHTML = '<span>No data found</span>';
            return;
        }

        var chartOptions = DEFAULT_PIE_CHART_OPTIONS;
        //var chartOverallPmmLevelCalculated = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
           // 'chartType': 'PieChart',
           // 'containerId': 'chartOverallPmmLevelCalculatedHtml',
            // options: chartOptions
        //});

        var chartRecentPmmLevelCalculated = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartOverallPmmLevelCalculatedHtml'));
        chartRecentPmmLevelCalculated.draw(dataTable, chartOptions);

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chartRecentPmmLevelCalculated, 'ready', function () { drawPieChart(); });
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chartRecentPmmLevelCalculated, 'select', function () { selectHandler(); });

        function drawPieChart() {
            var responseDataTable = response.getDataTable();
            var chartDataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            chartDataTable.addColumn('string', 'LEVEL');
            chartDataTable.addColumn('number', 'SCORE');
            var chartDataTableRow = new Array();
            var rowCounter;
            var levelValue;
            for (rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < responseDataTable.getNumberOfRows() ; rowCounter++) {
                var seek = 0 * 1;
                levelValue = responseDataTable.getValue(rowCounter, 0);
                chartDataTableRow[seek++] = "LEVEL " + levelValue;
                chartDataTableRow[seek++] = responseDataTable.getValue(rowCounter, 1);
                chartDataTable.addRow(chartDataTableRow);
            }
            chartDataTable.sort([{ column: 1 }]);
            chartOverallPmmLevelCalculated.setDataTable(chartDataTable);
            chartOverallPmmLevelCalculated.draw();
        }
        handlePieChartResponse.drawPieChart = drawPieChart;
    }

    function selectHandler() {
        alert("This alert triggered from pie chart");
        var selectedItem = chartRecentPmmLevelCalculated.getSelection();
        if (selectedItem) {
            var levelSelected = chartOverallPmmLevelCalculated.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
            alert(levelSelected);
        }
    }
```

I attached 2 images that include before and after the click. I was expecting alert message once select on pie chart slice. But no alert is present and the function call is not triggered.

[image: Before Click] [image: After Click on the slice]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem has to do with scope

`selectHandler` is outside of the function `handlePieChartResponse`

so it can't be found

just move it inside `handlePieChartResponse`

then set the event, like so...

```
...addListener(chartRecentPmmLevelCalculated, 'select', selectHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I always encounter these scope issues. Learned from mistakes.